# Camel is not deleting threads after throwing exception

Tags: java, out-of-memory, java-threads, spring-camel

I am facing the next problem: I have a camel route which throws an Exception to finish the execution. This Exception is caught in the camel-context.xml file where I log 2 messages. The problem of this is what when I receive many events on this route (3K in 5 minutes) the threads are not closed by camel, so I get a

> "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread"

Exception that stops the route

> "Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException:".

```
    Failed delivery for (MessageId: queue_comercial.tech.queue.patrimonialmutuactivos2salesforce_ID_c31189e4-c95d-11eb-86e0-02010a818cf6 on ExchangeId: ID-int-salesforce-events-48-jgv9b-1623268712584-0-4706). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-int-salesforce-events-48-jgv9b-1623268712584-0-4706];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.720268+00:00
Message History;,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.721787+00:00
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------;,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.722608+00:00
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms);,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.723272+00:00
[_routeRecibos     ] [_routeRecibos     ] [jms://queue://comercial.tech.queue.patrimonialmutuactivos2salesforce?cacheLeve] [        17];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.723988+00:00
[_routeRecibos     ] [_logRecibos1Header] [log                                                                           ] [         0];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.724822+00:00
[_routeRecibos     ] [_logRecibos1Body  ] [log                                                                           ] [         0];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.725480+00:00
[_routeRecibos     ] [_unmarshalRecibos ] [unmarshal[org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.JsonDataFormat@3ba5626a]          ] [         0];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.726417+00:00
[_routeRecibos     ] [_beanRecibosTransf] [bean[ref:entidadReciboToSalesforceTransformer method:transform]               ] [        15];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.727367+00:00
;,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.728144+00:00
Stacktrace;,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.728840+00:00
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------;,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.729590+00:00
org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-int-salesforce-events-48-jgv9b-1623268712584-0-4706];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.730306+00:00
011at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1846) ~[camel-core-2.21.0.fuse-000112-redhat-3.jar!/:2.21.0.fuse-000112-redhat-3];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.731106+00:00
011at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchange.setException(DefaultExchange.java:385) ~[camel-core-2.21.0.fuse-000112-redhat-3.jar!/:2.21.0.fuse-000112-redhat-3];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.731987+00:00
011at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:275) ~[camel-core-2.21.0.fuse-000112-redhat-3.jar!/:2.21.0.fuse-000112-redhat-3];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.732683+00:00
011at org.apache.camel.component.bean.AbstractBeanProcessor.process(AbstractBeanProcessor.java:187) ~[camel-core-2.21.0.fuse-000112-redhat-3.jar!/:2.21.0.fuse-000112-redhat-3];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.733315+00:00
011at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:53) ~[camel-core-2.21.0.fuse-000112-redhat-3.jar!/:2.21.0.fuse-000112-redhat-3];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.734075+00:00
011at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:76) ~[camel-core-2.21.0.fuse-000112-redhat-3.jar!/:2.21.0.fuse-000112-redhat-3];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.734738+00:00
011at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548) ~[camel-core-2.21.0.fuse-000112-redhat-3.jar!/:2.21.0.fuse-000112-redhat-3];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.735420+00:00
011at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [camel-core-2.21.0.fuse-000112-redhat-3.jar!/:2.21.0.fuse-000112-redhat-3];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.736151+00:00
011at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138) [camel-core-2.21.0.fuse-000112-redhat-3.jar!/:2.21.0.fuse-000112-redhat-3];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.736887+00:00
011at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101) [camel-core-2.21.0.fuse-000112-redhat-3.jar!/:2.21.0.fuse-000112-redhat-3];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.737642+00:00
011at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [camel-core-2.21.0.fuse-000112-redhat-3.jar!/:2.21.0.fuse-000112-redhat-3];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.738386+00:00
011at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97) [camel-core-2.21.0.fuse-000112-redhat-3.jar!/:2.21.0.fuse-000112-redhat-3];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.739176+00:00
011at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:113) [camel-jms-2.21.0.fuse-000112-redhat-3.jar!/:2.21.0.fuse-000112-redhat-3];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.739964+00:00
011at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:719) [spring-jms-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.740715+00:00
011at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:679) [spring-jms-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.741395+00:00
011at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:649) [spring-jms-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.742167+00:00
011at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:317) [spring-jms-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.742935+00:00
011at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:255) [spring-jms-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.743735+00:00
011at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1168) [spring-jms-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.744369+00:00
011at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1160) [spring-jms-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.745117+00:00
011at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1057) [spring-jms-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.745780+00:00
011at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_262];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.746429+00:00
011at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_262];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.747272+00:00
011at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_262];,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.748176+00:00
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread;,received_at=2021-06-09T20:04:04.748864+00:00
```

It happens every time I reboot the application, because I have many inbound events for this route waiting to be processed. Does anybody knows how can be camel configured to closed every single thread after every Exception?

My implementation:

The route:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
    <routeContext id="patrimonialRoutes" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route autoStartup="{{events.processors.ordenes.enabled:true}}" id="_routeOrdenes">
            <from id="_fromOrdenes" uri="jms:queue://{{events.queues.patrimonialvidaahorro2comercial}}?connectionFactory=#amqConnectionFactory&amp;receiveTimeout=60000&amp;transacted=true&amp;lazyCreateTransactionManager=false&amp;cacheLevelName=CACHE_CONSUMER&amp;errorHandlerLogStackTrace=false"/>
            <log id="_logOrdenes1Headers"
                logName="es.mma.comercial.sfdcevents.ordenes"
                loggingLevel="INFO" message="Recibida Orden patrimonial: HEADERS: ${headers}"/>
            <log id="_logOrdenes1Body"
                logName="es.mma.comercial.sfdcevents.ordenes"
                loggingLevel="INFO" message="Recibida Orden patrimonial: BODY: ${body}"/>
            <unmarshal id="_unmarshalOrdenes">
                <json library="Jackson" unmarshalTypeName="es.mma.comercial.sfdcevents.dto.EntidadOrden"/>
            </unmarshal>
            
            <!-- IN THIS BEAN IS WHERE THE EXCEPTION IS THROWN -->
            
            <bean id="_beanOrdenesTransformer1" method="transform" ref="entidadOrdenToSalesforceTransformer"/>
            ...
        </route>
```

The class that launch the Exception:

```
private String processResponseConsultaHistoricoPolizas(Response responseApiVidaAhorro) throws JsonProcessingException, JsonMappingException, IOException, JsonParseException, ApiVidaAhorroException {

    String idSolicitud = "";
    final String BLOQUE_TIPO_L = "L";
    mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<HistoricoPolizasBloqueTipo> historicoPolizasBloqueTipo = (List<HistoricoPolizasBloqueTipo>) mapper.readValue(responseApiVidaAhorro.body().string(), List.class);
    
    log.debug("### processResponseConsultaHistoricoPolizas: Respuesta consultaHistoricoPolizas: " + toString(historicoPolizasBloqueTipo));
    
    if ((historicoPolizasBloqueTipo == null) || (historicoPolizasBloqueTipo.size() == 0)) {
// HERE IS THE EXCEPTION

        throw new ApiVidaAhorroException(API_VIDA_AHORRO_RESPONSE_ERROR_EMPTY_BLOQUES);
    }
```

The camel-context that caught the Exception:

```
<camel:camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <camel:routeContextRef ref="patrimonialRoutes"/>
    
    <dataFormats>
        <json id="serializer" library="Jackson" />
    </dataFormats>

    <!-- Estrategia de reintentos de llamada a SF para envío de eventos DiH: -->
    <redeliveryPolicyProfile id="commErrorsRedeliveryPolicy" useExponentialBackOff="true" 
        redeliveryDelay="${camel.component.salesforce.redelivery-policy.delay}" 
        backOffMultiplier="${camel.component.salesforce.redelivery-policy.backOff-multiplier}" 
        maximumRedeliveryDelay="${camel.component.salesforce.redelivery-policy.maximum-delay}" 
        maximumRedeliveries="-1" logRetryAttempted="true" retryAttemptedLogLevel="WARN"
        logRetryStackTrace="false"/>

    <!-- Tratamiento de errores en la entrada de datos: se captura la excepción y a log. -->
    <onException>
        <exception>es.mma.comercial.sfdcevents.service.ApiVidaAhorroException</exception>

        <handled>
            <constant>true</constant>
        </handled>

        <log message="${exception.message}" loggingLevel="WARN" logName="es.mma.comercial.sfdcevents" />

        <!-- Esta cabecera es únicamente para los endpoints REST -->
        <setHeader headerName="Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE">
            <constant>400</constant>
        </setHeader>

        <transform>
            <simple>exception.message</simple>
        </transform>
        <log message="Caused by message: '${property.srcMessage}'" loggingLevel="WARN" logName="es.mma.comercial.sfdcevents" />
    </onException>
```